# WordPress Widget multiple use

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I created this widget using a simple example on WordPress Codex:

```
<?php

function widget_container_latest_posts() {
                             global $wpdb;
                  global $post;
                                get_template_part( '/includes/containers/container-latest-posts' );
}

wp_register_sidebar_widget(
    'widget_container_latest_posts_1',
    'Container Latest Posts',
    'widget_container_latest_posts',
    array( 
    'description' => 'Container Latest Posts - Adds recent posts.'
    )
);
?>
```

It works fine, but I want this widget to be used multiple times not only one time after I drag it on a sidebar widgets place, and so I can add it on all the other sidebars for example.
Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your Widget using the [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), so that WordPress knows how to make multiple instances of the Widget.

Your Widget declaration should take the following format:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function My_Widget() {
        // widget actual processes
    }

    function form($instance) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }

}
register_widget('My_Widget');
```